# Update shiny interface while processing data

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

How can I update the interface while processing data?

Here is the full story:

I am running a shiny app in a docker container. Before starting the app, I need to download a substantial amount of data (which takes some time). During that time it is not possible to connect to the shiny web server – since it has not started yet. However, I would like to make a simple page "Please wait, downloading data (XX%)" or something to that effect, and once the data is loaded, stop the app and run another one.

Below is a bit of code that kind of works. That is, the app runs, executes the "processing block" and when "data loading" is finished, stopApp is called and the results are returned. However, output is not being rendered until all the "work" has been done.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
                titlePanel("Please wait!"),
                fluidRow(
                         textOutput("msg")))

srv <- function(input, output) {

  output$msg <- renderText("Waiting")

  observe({
    ## the data loading block
    message("doing the job")
    Sys.sleep(10)

    message("proceeding")
    output$msg <- renderText("OK, proceeding")

    Sys.sleep(10)
    output$msg <- renderText("Nearly finished")
    message("nearly")

    Sys.sleep(10)
    message("done")
    stopApp(list(a=1, b=2))
  })
}

foo <- runApp(shinyApp(ui=ui, server=srv))
```

Now, what am I doing incorrectly? Even weirder, even the "Pleae wait" renderText call is not executed until everything is finished.

I think the problem is flushing. I assume that shiny waits with communicating with the JS in the browser until all reactive expressions have finished evaluating. I don't know how to tell it to update the UI immediately.

I guess could split the processing into a chain of reactive expressions that depend one on another and interact with the interface, updating interface bit by bit, but firstly, that would be hardly scalable (I need to load several data sets and I don't know their number beforehand) and secondly it would look weird. Most importantly, I tried several approaches and I failed. Best solution I came up with was something like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
                titlePanel("Please wait!"),
                fluidRow(
                         numericInput("xxx", label="testlab", value=0),
                         textOutput("msg")))

srv <- function(input, output, session) {

  steps <- reactiveVal(1)

  observe({
    message("starting stuff")
      updateNumericInput(session=session, inputId="xxx", value=1)
  })
    
  observeEvent(input$xxx, {

    n <- req(input$xxx)

    message("Running job ", n)
    Sys.sleep(10)
    updateNumericInput(inputId="xxx", value=n + 1)

    if(n == 3) {
      stopApp(list(steps=n, done=TRUE))
    }
  })

  output$msg <- renderText({
    n <- req(input$xxx)
    return(sprintf("Processing job %d", n))
  })
}

foo <- runApp(shinyApp(ui=ui, server=srv))
```

Is there a simple trick that I'm missing?

Comment: R is single threaded. You'll need to [run your download asynchronously](https://github.com/rstudio/promises/issues/23#issuecomment-386687705) to stop blocking the UI. Furthermore library([ipc](https://github.com/fellstat/ipc)) might be of interest.

Comment: Nope, I don't want to update anything *while* downloading. The code in my example is sequential: download something, update the interface, download something other, update the interface again. The Waiter package does the job nicely.

Comment: Well, your initial question was: `How can I update the interface while processing data?` .. a little misleading regarding your above statement.

Comment: OK, fair point, I thought the example would make it clear. But you are right, I should have been more verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?
[Source](https://github.com/JohnCoene/waiter)

```
library(shiny)
library(waiter)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useWaitress(),
  p("App content")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  # call the waitress
  waitress <- Waitress$
    new(theme = "overlay-percent")$
    start() # start

# insert data loading here instead of the for loop
# put some waitress$inc(X) between loading data if your data
# is composed of several variables

  for(i in 1:10){
    waitress$inc(10) # increase by 10%
    Sys.sleep(.3)
  }

  # hide when it's done
  waitress$close() 

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```